# How can I resize a NSTextView automatically based on the size of the contents?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I am implementing an iChat-like app, using `NSTextView` to display chat records. The problem is how to change the width of `NSTextView` automatically based on characters in it. For example, the width of `NSTextView` is only one character width if there's only one character in it. More than 100 characters will automatically increase the height of `NSTextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [string addition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000155) `[-NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:]` to get a bounding rectangle. You might also want to look into the [Layout Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/TextLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000158-SW1).